# SVG images not showing up in Chrome after going through javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a sticky footer on my page, but the SVG files won't show up in chrome if I enable the javascript which makes sure the SVG images change color on hover. Removing the javascript causes Chrome to load the images fine.

I am not able to recreate the effect in the jsfiddle, but here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/r9szd060/

This is the javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( 'img[src$=".svg"]' ).each( function () {
        var $img = jQuery( this );
        var imgURL = $img.attr( 'src' );
        var attributes = $img.prop( "attributes" );

        $.get( imgURL, function ( data ) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery( data ).find( 'svg' );

            // Remove any invalid XML tags
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr( 'xmlns:a' );

            // Loop through IMG attributes and apply on SVG
            $.each( attributes, function () {
                $svg.attr( this.name, this.value );
            } );

            // Replace IMG with SVG
            $img.replaceWith( $svg );
        }, 'xml' );
    } );
} );
```

I've tried using the embed tag instead of the img tag, but that doesn't change the behavior in chrome. Firefox (desktop + iOS + Android) handles the SVG images fine, as does Safari (desktop + iOS). The SVG images disappear in Chrome on desktop and chrome on android. Strangely, chrome on iOS does work...

I think it has something to do with the way the SVG is handled through the javascript and how the SVG is saved, but I am not well versed enough in javascript to pick up on the problem. I've read that chrome sometimes has some issues with SVG files? I don't know how to upload the SVG file itself so that you can see, but if someone can tell me how I can pass through relevant information (from the file opened in illustrator for example) I will add it to this post :).

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I can solve it?

Comment: jQuery is not included in your fiddle ?!

Comment: The script is there, I've checked. Don't know if its jQuery or javascript though. Like I said, I'm not very good at it, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style any SVG with CSS, you must set an attribute on it, for the width. It's why you don't see them in the page, each SVG take his real size (about 600px.)

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( 'img[src$=".svg"]' ).each( function () {
        var $img = jQuery( this );
        var imgURL = $img.attr( 'src' );
        var attributes = $img.prop( "attributes" );

        $.get( imgURL, function ( data ) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery( data ).find( 'svg' );

            // Remove any invalid XML tags
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr( 'xmlns:a' );

            // Loop through IMG attributes and apply on SVG
            $.each( attributes, function () {
                $svg.attr( this.name, this.value );
            } );

            //Add width on newly created svg
            $svg.attr('width', '30'); 

            // Replace IMG with SVG
            $img.replaceWith( $svg );
        }, 'xml' );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: The images I used are smaller (I think I saved them 30x30 or something like that). That said, why does it work in every browser except Chrome, if the attributes are missing? I tested your code, and it works, so I'll accept this as the answer :). Still curious about the difference in browsers though.

Comment: It's a good question, I got the same behaviour on mozilla and chrome on my side. It's just not possible to apply css to svg :(

Comment: But I AM applying css to a SVG image, and it's working too. The 'old' code and the newly answered code. On hover it changes the image color. Works perfectly (in every browser except chrome) :-)

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was bad, I mean, you can't style svg width and height with CSS. About the color changing, it work's for me on chrome (version 59.0)

Comment: Oh, in that way. Thanks :). I've got v59 as well, but with the old code it didn't work in chrome, however new code does so my issue is solved either way!